# How to exit SFTP when cd command fails

Tags: shell, sftp, exit-code

Shell script for file transfer by SFTP is already written and working fine on AIX Version 6.1. I am developing ETL with SAP Data Services and real new to shell scripting. During unit testing, I provided non-existent target folder for SFTP to simulate a case if target folder name was changed by a user, but it did not fail after command **cd** and returned exit code 0, though echoing error message: **Couldn't canonicalise: Failure**. That makes ETL process not aware that file was not transferred. When I injected exit 1 in script, the ETL job caught the SFTP failure and failed itself, which is an expected behaviour.

My question is: How can I tweak existing shell script invoking SFTP command to exit with code 1?

Here is excerpt from script:

```
'#!/bin/sh
```

....

```
echo cd $TARGET_REMOTE_DIR>>$INPUT_FILE

echo put $TARGET_LOCAL_DIR$TARGET_FILE_NAME>>$INPUT_FILE

echo quit>>$INPUT_FILE

/usr/bin/sftp -b $INPUT_FILE $USER@$HOSTNAME
```

I `echo` `$?` variable right after command `cd`, it returns 0 when remote dir is spelled wrong. What I am thinking is probably checking in-line for existence of an error message after command `cd` and if its length is not 0 then exit with code 1.

Something like in pseudo code:

```
error_msg = get_error_msg({cd $TARGET_REMOTE_DIR>>$INPUT_FILE})

if length(trim(error_msg)) <> 0 then
echo “Cannot change directory! Aborting…”

exit 1

fi
```

Any comments are appreciated.

Cheers!

With great help from Martin I have implemented this solution: Catching $? return code right after command /usr/bin/sftp and forcing to exit with caught error!

```
/usr/bin/sftp -b $INPUT_FILE $USER@$HOSTNAME

if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
  " SFTP Error while accessing remote target directory! Error message"
  exit $?
fi
```

Thank you all! Great forum!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I assume, you are using OpenSSH `sftp`.

The OpenSSH `sftp` indeed aborts the script and exits with `1`, when `cd` command fails.

So you problem is probably not with the SFTP script, but in a way you capture the exit code.

If you share details, how you capture the exit code, you may get more concrete answer.

As for your test with `echo $?`:
Where do you put `echo $?` command? To your SFTP script (`$INPUT_FILE`)? `sftp` does not have an `echo` command; and it cannot resolve `$?` either.

If you put it to the shell script like this:

```
echo cd $TARGET_REMOTE_DIR>>$INPUT_FILE
echo $?
```

it does not do, what you want. You are here just querying result of previous `echo` command, which is unlikely to ever fail.

Comment: Thank you for reply. When I change spelling of remote directory, sftp actually returns error 'not found', but the error code is still 0. I was inserting echo $? in different places within the script, it always 0. Is it possible to capture just error message? And if its length is not 0, then force existing with error code other than 0?

Comment: Did you try to put `echo $?` after the `/usr/bin/sftp ...`? That's the only place where it can work and it indeed does.

Comment: Thanks again for reply. Yes, I tried catching $? right after that line within if then fi and it did work! It also returns code and error message itself! My "reputation" rating does not allow to rate your answer...